# Me sale este error al ingresar a mi dominio, tengo una cuenta godaddy y el proyecto esta hecho en php

Tags: php, godaddy

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Controller' not found in /home/admingrupobecm/public_html/ELSURTAMBIENEXISTE.ORG/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php:177 Stack trace: #0 /home/admingrupobecm/public_html/ELSURTAMBIENEXISTE.ORG/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(95): ExceptionRenderer->_getController(Object(FatalErrorException)) #1 /home/admingrupobecm/public_html/ELSURTAMBIENEXISTE.ORG/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(126): ExceptionRenderer->__construct(Object(FatalErrorException)) #2 /home/admingrupobecm/public_html/ELSURTAMBIENEXISTE.ORG/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(284): ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(FatalErrorException)) #3 /home/admingrupobecm/public_html/ELSURTAMBIENEXISTE.ORG/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(213): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(64, 'Cannot use 'Obj...', '/home/admingrup...', 30) #4 /home/admingrupobecm/public_html/ELSURTAMBIENEXISTE.ORG/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(970): ErrorHandler::handleError(64, 'Cannot use 'Obj...', '/home/admingrup...', 30, Array) #5 /home/admingrupobecm/public_html/E in /home/admingrupobecm/public_html/ELSURTAMBIENEXISTE.ORG/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php on line 177

Comment: No se cómo resolver tu duda, pero tal vez te soliciten la estructura de tus directorios (en godaddy).

Comment: Gracias por responder ! Al final resultó problema de versiones de la página, actualize su versión y funcionó con normalidad.